# Email validation using NSFormatter

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsformatter

I know this maybe an invalid question.

For email validation, I will go with regex and `NSPredicate`. But I was asked this, hence trying to get your views on this.

How to use `NSFormatter` to validate an `NSTextField` for an email address?

I can do it without `NSFormatter` using regex. But just curious to know is this possible to do it using NSFormatter?

If yes, how? Any guidance will be helpful.

Comment: A formatter is just a way to transform two a value into another one (usually "human" to machine, and reverse, like a Date, etc.). The validation isn't part of that, it's your business internally to decide that, and you can use a regex there. Because currently, with you Formatter, you'll transform a email adresse into an email address? No changes?

Comment: @Larme See [NSFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsformatter?language=occ) "A custom formatter can restrict the input and enhance the display of data in novel ways. For example, you could have a custom formatter that ensures that serial numbers entered by a user conform to predefined formats."

Comment: The documentation of `NSFormatter` refers to [Creating a Custom Formatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/CreatingACustomFormatter.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000196). Have you tried this?

Answer (score 1):

> But just curious to know is this possible to do it using NSFormatter?

[`NSFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsformatter) is intended to be subclassed, with each subclass corresponding to a particular kind of data. That's why we have `NSDateFormatter`, `NSNumberFormatter`, `NSMassFormatter`, etc.

As far as I'm aware, the Foundation framework doesn't provide an `NSFormatter` subclass specifically for email addresses, so you'll need to either find one that someone else has written or write your own. Take a look at [`NSPersonNameComponentsFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nspersonnamecomponentsformatter) for an example of how your `EmailFormatter` class might work. There's an ancillary [`NSPersonNameComponents`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nspersonnamecomponents) class that contains the various pieces of a full name, and the formatter has methods like `-stringFromPersonNameComponents:` and `-personNameComponentsFromString:` to convert between the components object and a string.

You'll probably want to do something similar: create a class or structure that can contain the various parts of an email address, and then write methods that converts an instance of that class to and from a string. To use the formatter to validate an address given as a string, use the formatter to convert the string to your components object, and then check that all the required fields in that object have legitimate values.

Answer (score -2):

Use this code

```
  extension String {
// This code is for checking if url is valid, to do email, you need to change the `regEx`
        var validURL: Bool {
            get {
                let regEx = "((?:http|https)://)?(?:www\\.)?[\\w\\d\\-_]+\\.\\w{2,3}(\\.\\w{2})?(/(?<=/)(?:[\\w\\d\\-./_]+)?)?"
                let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", argumentArray: [regEx])
                return predicate.evaluate(with: self)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your code isn't wrong, but you haven't answered the OP's question. The OP already said he/she will use a predicate, but was asking how and if a formatter could be used instead.